# how to pass data from javascript to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, social-networking

I am working on a plugin for a static site that creates a sort of social link locker.

I am trying to pass data from the javascript to my json but i am having some issues. Code snippet below.

It's a bit long but i'm trying to pass the curr_page variable into the json string so that each page is shared properly. If i manually type in a static url the buttons work, if I try to pass in the page or curr_page variable, it doesn't work.

How can I pass the curr_page variable into that json string?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var curr_page = window.location.href;
        page = String(curr_page);
        console.log(curr_page);
        console.log(page);
        $("#sharer").sociallocker({
            text: {
                header: "Grab the extra resources",
                message: "Please support us, click like button below to unlock the content."
            },

            locker: {
                close: false,
                timer: 0
            },

            buttons: {   
                order: ["facebook-like", "twitter-tweet", "twitter-follow", "google-plus"]
            },

            facebook: {
                like: {
                    title: "Like",
                    url: "https://www.facebook.com/[]"
                }
            },

            twitter: {
                tweet: {
                    title: "Tweet",
                    text: "[]",
                    url: page 
                },
                follow: {
                    title: "Follow us",
                    url: "https://twitter.com/[username]"
                }
            },

            google: {
                plus: {
                    title: "google-share",
                    url: page
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the output to the console.log() functions?

Comment: the console will log the correct page ex: http://domain.com/correct-url but trying to make it a string and pass it into the json as 'page' it doesn't work, neither does trying to directly access 'curr_page' in the json seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I hope I understand you right...

If you want to set / add a value to a JSON you just do it like

```
myJSON.myKey = "myValue";
myJSON.myKey.mySubKey = "myValue";
```

Thats all...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want, but if you only want to pass the current page you can put directly `url: window.location.href`.

To be clear here, this is a javascript object, not a JSON string. You can pass variables or return from a function to the `url:`.

I can't understand why isn't working for you.

Check my Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a1r9j1Ld/)

Answer (score -1):

By passing the current page url, you are redirecting the page to itself, by providing the link to itself, in page variable.

```
   url: page
```

here, the url is referring to the current page only. and these social buttons on clicking will only reload the same page.